# Customize bootstrap carousel indicators

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, I have a carousel with three images and I need to customize the carousel indicators with `dots` which resume to: if I have an active carousel [image: active dot] and the other should be like [image: dot], so I tried this :

```
.carousel-indicators li{
   background: url(../images/dot.png) no-repeat;
   max-width:25%;
   max-height:15%; 
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Here's [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/95AtM/1/)! Any way I can achieve that? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95AtM/2/)

You'll need to alter the carousel so the `active` class is correctly added to the right `li` on slide change, then try adding the below to your CSS:

```
.pagination li a, .pagination li:last-child a, .pagination li:first-child a  {
    border-radius:100%;
    background:teal;  
    color:transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2px;
}

.pagination li.active a, .pagination li.active:last-child a, .pagination li.active:first-child a  {
    border-radius:100%;
    background:black;    
    height:10px;
    line-height:10px;
    width:10px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```